# passing data with navigation frame

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8

I am developing an app for windows phone 8.1, I have three pages, I'm using the  `Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page2),nav)` to pass data between pages, I'm using a class

```
public class PassedData
{
   public string Name { get; set; } 
   public string Name1 { get; set; } 
   public string Name3 { get; set; }
   public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

for the object:

```
var nav = (passedData)e.Parameter;
myTextBlock.Text = nav.Name;
mytex1.Text = nav.Name1;
```

my problem how do the object for the int value? I have a problem with the conversion type int in the object.

Comment: your "Value" value maybe in null condition, make sure it has integer value.

Comment: if the user type the value in a textbox, how i can use it?

Comment: you can set the <TextBox InputScope="Number" x:Name="myTextBox"/> and set the value of the textbox to your object.

For Example :

var passedData= new PassedData;
passedData.Name="Name";
passedData.Name1="Name1";
passedData.Name3="Name3";
passedData.Value=int.Parse(myTextBox.Text);

then you can pass your passedData

Comment: thanks a lot, let me see......

Comment: doesnt work, i dont find the problem yet

Comment: You can share me a repro project, so I can assist you easier

Comment: it works,  thanks @GaneshSalim i find a solution, do you want  assist me with my project?

Comment: how i can give you a +1 to your comment?

Comment: i have one more question, if i passed information in one page with the class passed data, can i pass information of another page with the same class but different object?

Comment: no problem, you can upvote my comment if you want.
Yes you can pass any objects to any Pages.

Comment: thanks, im going to try it

Comment: i have this problem System.InvalidCastException when i try pass info from one page to another, i have this class public class navigation
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int value { get; set; }
}

Comment: it works for one page, but when i try pass a second page, i have the system,invalidcastexception, i call the class from a second page
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {            var nav = (navigation)e.Parameter;
            
                mytext1.Text = nav.name;
                mytext2.Text = nav.value.ToString();           

             text2.Text = nave.value.ToString();
           text1.Text = nave.name;
           
        }
public class navigation
    {
        public string name { get; set; }        public int value { get; set; }
}

Answer (score 0):

just try this

int convertValue = 0;

var passedData= new PassedData;
 passedData.Name="Name"; passedData.Name1="Name1"; passedData.Name3="Name3";

long number1 = 0;

```
bool canConvert = long.TryParse(myTextBox.Text, out convertValue );
```

if (canConvert == true)
{

passedData.Value=   Convert.ToInt32(myTextBox.Text);
}

I think it will works

Comment: when i run the app in the windows phone, i try to navigate between pages, i have this problem if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();